# I'm trying to make a game where I push a button and the number of times that the button is pressed is displayed

Tags: javascript, khan-academy

this is written in Javascript btw.
I am just beginning to write code. everything I have learned is from khanacademy.org and this code is written in their code so it may be different IDK though :/
I am still on Intro To JS: Drawing and Animation.

QUESTION: why does it keep saying NaN for not a number when I run it? How do I fix it?

here is the code:

---

```
var buttonPressedNum = 0;
var buttonSize = 150;

var draw = function() {

background (50, 150, 250);


fill(250, 150, 50);
ellipse(200, 250, buttonSize, buttonSize);
fill(0, 0, 0);
textSize(31);
text('PUSH ME', 130, 255);


if(mouseX > 125, mouseX < 275, mouseY > 175, mouseY < 325) {
    if(mouseIsPressed) {
        var buttonPressedNum = buttonPressedNum + 1;
    }
}

var buttonPressedNum = buttonPressedNum + 0;


fill(255, 0, 0);
textSize(37);
text ('Clicks: ' + buttonPressedNum, 91, 100);

};
```

sorry if formatting is bad this is my first post

Comment: There is no question here.  You need to add a specific question about what your problem is, or your post is likely to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, what's the question? Are you getting compile errors? Is it just not working?

From looking at this it's just going to count up the button press count regardless of the IF statement and then end.

you'd need the count and the display to only run inside the if statement where it checks the location and which mouse button

you also probably only want this entire script to run on button press otherwise it's going to constantly update with the press count every cycle and probably just crash

Comment: I have no idea why it won't work. Instead of displaying numButtonPressed it displays NaN

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you unfortunately. Any chance you could show a bit more? Like maybe `text` implementation? What is `numButtonPressed`, it doesn't seem to exist in the snippet you shared

Comment: sorry I meant ```buttonPressedNum```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement to check if the mouse is in the right spot and being pressed is incorrect. On Khan Academy, when having many conditions in an if statement, you place double ampersands(&&) between the conditions. Your code would look like this:

```
if(mouseX > 125 && mouseX < 275 && mouseY > 175 && mouseY < 325) {
    if(mouseIsPressed) {
        var buttonPressedNum = buttonPressedNum + 1;
    }
}
```